# pandas-profiling showing the error of styles not in the library, how can I add the style?

Tags: styles, pandas-profiling

from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport as pr

profile = pr(csv_data)

profile

Error: 'C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\envs\dataPipe\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\pandas_profiling.mplstyle' not found in the style library and input is not a valid URL or path; see `style.available` for list of available styles

I tried uninstall and reinstall pandas-profiling using .zip, or different versions (such as 2.6.0, 2.7.1) and nothing fixes it. The current version is the default 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it as follows:

1. upgrade pip via

conda update pip

2. uninstall python-profiling

pip uninstall pandas-profiling

3. Reinstall python-profiling

pip install python-profiling[notebook,html]

Cheers, Leo